# DB2 Select from two tables when one table requires sum

Tags: sql, database, db2

In a DB2 Database, I want to do the following simple mathematics using a SQL query:

> AvailableStock = SupplyStock - DemandStock

SupplyStock is stored in 1 table in 1 row, let's call this table the Supply table.
So the **Supply** table has this data:

```
ProductID | SupplyStock
---------------------
109            10
244             7  edit: exclude this product from the search
```

DemandStock is stored in a separate table Demand, where demand is logged as each customer logs demand during a customer order journey. Example data from the Demand table:

```
ProductID | DemandStock 
------------------------
109            1
244            4  edit: exclude this product
109            6
109            2
```

So in our heads, if I want to calculate the AvailableStock for product '109', Supply is 10, Demand for product 109 totals to 9, and so Available stock is 1.

How do I do this in **one select query** in DB2 SQL?

The knowledge I have so far of some of the imagined steps in PseudoCode:

- I select SupplyStock where product ID = '109'
- I select sum(DemandStock) where product ID  = '109'
- I subtract SupplyStock from DemandStock
- I present this as a resulting AvailableStock

The results will look like this:

```
Product ID | AvailableStock
109                9
```

I'd love to get this selected in one SQL select query.

***Edit:*** I've since received an answer (that was almost perfect) and realised the question missed out some information.
This information:
We need to exclude data from products we don't want to select data for, and we also need to specifically select product 109. 
My apologies, this was omitted from the original question.
I've since added a 'where' to select the product and this works for me. But for future sake, perhaps the answer should include this information too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this using a `join` to bring the tables together and `group by` to aggregate the results of the `join`:

```
select s.ProductId, s.SupplyStock, sum(d.DemandStock),
       (s.SupplyStock - sum(d.DemandStock)) as Available
from Supply s left join
     Demand d
     on s.ProductId = d.ProductId 
where s.ProductId = 109
group by s.ProductId, s.SupplyStock;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, your answer was almost perfect, happy to accept this answer.
However, I missed out a part of the question that was crucial - that we need to select only product '109' and omit demand and supply from other products.
Maybe you would want to update your answer to show this?
(e.g. what I did was effectively: where s.ProductId = '109') after the 'on s.ProductId = d.ProductId' line.